# Set Away/Home Mode

Tags: google-api, nest-device-access, google-sdm-api

Does the API expose the ability to set the mode to Away or Home?

I don’t see this listed in the API documentation. I think this functionality is important as it now only allows you to turn off your thermostats but also configure alerts via the mobile app (I have mine set to only send alerts for my NestCams when I’m away).

Answer (score 1):

You can't set "away", but you can set the thermostat to either Eco or Off.

Answer (score 0):

No. I also hope the old functionality of the Nest API's will be available on the new API. The motion/person per zone is also missing for example.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to explicitly set that in this new API. Google wants you to use their Home/Away Routines instead, though I don't think all of the old use cases are supported yet (or will be).

https://support.google.com/googlenest/answer/10071816